# Passing arguments to Objective C class in Swift

Tags: objective-c, class, swift

Objective-Class:

```
@interface EpsonIo: NSObject {
@private
    void *handle_;
}

- (id) init;

- (void) dealloc;

- (int) open:(int)deviceType DeviceName:(NSString *)deviceName DeviceSettings:(NSString *)deviceSettings;

- (int) close;

- (int) write:(NSData *)data Offset:(size_t)offset Size:(int)size Timeout:(long)timeout SizeWritten:(size_t *)sizeWritten;

- (int) read:(NSMutableData *)data Offset:(size_t)offset Size:(size_t)size Timeout:(long)timeout SizeRead:(size_t *)sizeRead;

@end
```

I'm trying to use this class to print with my Epson printer. In my old Objective-C project, I can print it without any problems.

Old Objective-C:

```
// print document
EpsonIo *port = [[EpsonIo alloc] init];
if (port != nil)
{
    int errorStatus = EPSONIO_OC_SUCCESS;

    errorStatus = [port open:EPSONIO_OC_DEVTYPE_TCP DeviceName: @"192.168.1.168" DeviceSettings:nil];
    if (EPSONIO_OC_SUCCESS == errorStatus)
    {
        // settings for sending
        unsigned long sizeWritten;
        int errStatus;
        NSData *data = builder.data;

        errStatus = [port write:data Offset:0 Size:[data length] Timeout:100 SizeWritten: &sizeWritten];

        errorStatus = [port close];
    }
}
```

In Swift I'm getting various errors like "Int is not convertible to Int32", "Uint is not convertible to UnsafeMutablePointer"

Swift:

```
var printFile = EpsonIo()

        var errorStatus: Int32 = 0

        errorStatus = printFile.open(257, deviceName: "192.168.1.168", deviceSettings: nil)

        var printData: NSData = printText.data

        var sizeWritten: CUnsignedLong = 0

        var newStatus = printFile.write(printData, offset: 0, size: Int(printData.length), timeout: 100, sizeWritten: sizeWritten)
```

I've tried for hours and Googled as much as possible but I just can't figure it out... Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
var sizeWritten: size_t = 0        // CUnsignedLong -> size_t

var newStatus = printFile.write(
    printData,
    offset: 0,
    size: Int32(printData.length), // UInt -> Int32
    timeout: 100,
    sizeWritten: &sizeWritten      // Add prefix &
)
```

- In Swift, `UInt` and `Int32` are different type and cannot be casted implicitly.
- `sizeWritten` parameter is defined as a C pointer, which can be described `&` in Swift.